# Find the smallest number of square numbers to create n

Tags: java, performance, interview-questions

An interview question I got -

Given int `n`, find the smallest number of square numbers that fit inside `n`.

Example:

```
Input: 24 
Output: 3 (16 + 4 + 4)

Input: 10
Output: 2 (9 + 1)
```

Solution:

```
public class Solution{
    public static int solution(int number){
        int squareCount = 0;
        while(number> 0){
            int square = (int)Math.sqrt(number);
            squareCount++;
            number-=square*square;
        }       
        return squareCount; 
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Must be Java 7
- Must be in class called `Solution`, with a `public static int solution(int number)` method
- Must not use any 3rd party libraries

I like this solution because it is very simple, however it does have one inefficiency. It finds the square root only to perform a squaring operation again. It would be nice if I could find the largest square number in squared form immediately, but I cant think of an efficient way to do this.

Comment: This solution is incorrect. For input `18` it returns the solution `3` (16 + 1 + 1) while the correct solution is `2` (9 + 9).

Answer (score 5):

Your solution seems to be the most efficient, except for the fact that it doesn't seem to work. You could try finding all possible groups like so:

$$18=4^2+1^2+1^2$$

$$18=3^2+3^2$$

$$18=3^2+2^2+2^2+1^2$$

$$...$$

Then find the smallest group.

Your code would sure like some space. After some nice, wide spacing:

```
public static int solution(int number) {
    int squareCount = 0;
    while(number > 0){
        int square = (int) Math.sqrt(number);
        squareCount++;
        number -= square * square;
    }       
    return squareCount; 
}
```

I will post a possible solution after I figure one out.